# set the variables that go inside array_merge_recursive

Tags: php

I need to tell array_merge_recursive what variables it needs to merge

I have the variable names that I need to use as strings, for example I have the following

```
$array1 = array('color'=>'blue', 'taste'=> 'sour', 'size'=>'big');
$array2 = array('color'=>'green', 'taste'=> 'sweet', 'size'=>'medium');
$array3 = array('color'=>'black', 'taste'=> 'sour', 'size'=>'small');
$array4 = array('color'=>'grey', 'taste'=> 'sweet', 'size'=>'big');

$allarrays = array_merge_recursive($array1, $array2, $array3, $array4);
```

This will work okay and merge my arrays, but I need to add a foreach to get the list of the arrays that I need and to set the array's that are going to the merged.

```
$arraysThatINeedToAddToTheMerge = array('array2', 'array4');

foreach ($arraysThatINeedToAddToTheMerge as $data){

    $toBeMerged[] = $data;

}

$allarrays = array_merge_recursive($toBeMerged);
```

This doesn't work as it looks like I cannot use an array as the arguments for the array_merge_recursive.
I was thinking maybe I can use the list function for this but I haven't used it yet, what can I use to get what I need?

Answer (score 1):

Two elements to handling this the way you want to:

Variable variables to build the to be merged array

```
$arraysThatINeedToAddToTheMerge = array('array2', 'array4');

$toBeMerged = [];
foreach ($arraysThatINeedToAddToTheMerge as $data){
    $toBeMerged[] = $$data;
}
```

This will build an array of arrays, rather than simply an array of the names of your variables;

---

And (a modern PHP solution) then unpack the array arguments to be merged when calling array_merge_recursive

```
$allarrays = array_merge_recursive(...$toBeMerged);
```

or use `call_user_func_array()` for older versions of PHP

```
$allarrays = call_user_func_array('array_merge_recursive', $toBeMerged);
```